# Handling Java Interupts

Tags: java, concurrency

I am making an application that will work much like a real time chat. A user will be constantly writing on lets say a text area and messages will be send to other users. On the communications class I have set up a receiver. When a message from someone reaches the client, the receive method will be invoked and will get the message. What I can't understand is how the code will be executed. What happens if, while the user is typing/sending a message the receive message is invoked ? What do I need to do in order for this to work properly ? 
Hope the question is clear enough.

ps : Im still in the design phase thats why I haven't tested it to see what happens.
Also atm I only use a second thread to receive messages which calls the receive method.

Comment: Could you describe what you  mean by "while the user is typing/sending a message"? Is this a console mode program? If it's a GUI program, then you will be using an event driven framework of some kind so there is no "while". You just get user key press events, and you decide what to do with each one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should not be a problem at all.

> When a message from someone reaches the client, the receive method
>   will be invoked and will get the message. What I can't understand is
>   how the code will be executed?

You should have a Receiver class that will encapsulate a socket (from which your receive data) and keep a set of listeners (see [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)). A GUI can be one of the listeners. When a message is received via the socket, you need to notify all listeners by forwarding the data received. This way, you have a clean and nice way to notify the GUI about new messages arrivals.

> What happens if, while the user is typing/sending a message the
>   receive message is invoked ?

This depends on the type of IP protocol you are using but in general your don't have to worry about this although I suggest you protect your sockets using [lock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) mechanisms.

What do I need to do in order for this to work properly ?
Here is a nice [example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/java/java_applet_chat_with_gui.aspx) that can give you some inspiration :)

**EDIT:** As for your question regarding execution flow, sending and receiving are two different and uncorrelated operations that can happen at the same time. This can be achieved by implementing send and receive operations in two different threads. Here is an [article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/socket-140484.html) on socket communications and multithreading.

Comment: My main concern is what happens with flow of execution. For example while the application is in the process of sending a message, and the receive method is invoked , will the sending of the message stop and the new message get displayed then the sending continues or will the message be send and the new message is displayed later or will the application crash and get some exception?

Comment: Thanks for your response . I got one last question. Is it possible to do this : when a message is received, the application stops whatever its doing, updates the GUI with the new message or whatever has to be done, and then it goes back to whatever it was doing before. I have done some programming using threads before (client-server) but nothing too complicated. Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

You should either do what traditional Java EE app servers have done, which is assign a separate thread for processing each incoming message, or try a Java NIO solution along the lines of Netty.

Comment: Incoming messages will simply be read and send to the correct panel to display them. The same panel that will display incoming messages will be receiving input for messages to send .This operation needs two threads ?